# Javascript: Mudar fundo e mostrar seleções em TEXTAREA resultando em erro 405

Tags: javascript, array, if

Olá! Esse exercício é o seguinte:

Clicar no botão vai:

- Mudar a cor do fundo
- Mostrar a seleção de jornais no textarea

Quando clico no botão, a página resulta em erro 405. Não estou encontrando o bug e no console nem no VS está aparecendo erro.

O HTML está assim:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Radio buttons and Checkboxes</h1>
  <form action="" method="post" id="backg">
    <div>Please select a background color for the form:</div>
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" />Green </label>
      <label
        ><input type="radio" name="colors" value="yellow" />Yellow
      </label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="colors" value="lime" />Lime </label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="colors" value="aqua" />Aqua </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      Please select your favorite magazines: <br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mags" value="The New Yorker" />
        The New Yorker </label
      ><br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mags" value="WIRED" />
        WIRED </label
      ><br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mags" value="National Geographic" />
        National Geographic </label
      ><br />
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mags" value="Sports Illustrated" />
        Sports Illustrated
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Your magazine selections:<br />
        <textarea name="result" cols="30" rows="4" readonly></textarea>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="button" value="Select" id="selectBtn" />
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Clear" id="resetBtn" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

O javascript está assim:

```html
<script>
  function select() {
    const myForm = document.getElementById('backg');
    const colors = myForm['colors'];

    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      if (colors[i].checked) {
        let userChoice = colors[i].value;
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = userChoice;
      }
    }
  }

  function displayMags() {
    const myFormTwo = document.getElementById('backg');
    const magazine = selectForm['mags'];

    let message = magazine;
    myFormTwo['result'].value = message;
  }

  document.getElementById('selectBtn').onclick = select;
  document.getElementById('selectBtn').onclick = displayMags;
</script>
```

Comment: Isso nao acontece por causa desse `input` do tipo `submit`? Desse jeito voce esta submetendo o formulario para um endereco que o servidor nao consegue resolver (`action=""`). Nao deveria colocar o tipo `button` para esse `input`? Ficaria assim: `<input type="button" name="button" value="Select" id="selectBtn" />`

Comment: Outra coisa, quando voce atribui `document.getElementById('selectBtn').onclick = displayMags;`, voce estar sobreescrevendo a atribuicao anterior `document.getElementById('selectBtn').onclick = select;`.